# How add view over TextureView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, textureview, android-textureview

i need to add `View` over my `TextureView` which play video in it
i used `VideoView` before and it was totally fine but i had problem with animation so i changed it to `TextureView` and now i can't put any `View` over it!
seems that `Textureview` will cover over all views
this is my xml layout :

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frmview"
    >

    <com.my.app.TextureVideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv_play"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:alpha="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_ic" />
</FrameLayout>
```

How can i put a `View` over `TextureView` which is playing video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i had to add it programmically to my `FrameLayout` after initializing `TextureView` and playing video!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    mPreview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.vv_play);
    mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frmview);

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_ic);
    frameLayout.addView(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this api of TextureView:

TextureView.setOpaque(false);

Answer (score 0):

`TextureView` that constantly updates its content (e.g. playing video) will always overdraw any `View` content that is put on the top of it (e.g. `TextureView` and some other `View` puted inside `FrameLayout` container).

The best solution I found to handle that is to show the top `View` inside another `Window` that sits on top of `Window` that contains `TextureView`, e.g. `PopupWindow` can be used for that.