# Programmatically add visible views to Android textureview

Tags: java, android, textureview

I want to know if it's possible to programmatically add a view to the texture view (camera2).

If I add the texture view to a frame layout which has a view in it, then that view is not visible.

Comment: I think you can add

Comment: Please provide details why view isnt visible

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339131/how-add-view-over-textureview/38339774

Comment: I don't know why it's invisible.

Comment: please share xml code and java code

Comment: For me, I cannot access / write XML code.